# Writing infinite list to skip every factor of p?

Tags: performance, math, haskell, functional-programming, arithmetic-expressions

How can I efficiently represent the list `[0..] \\ [t+0*p, t+1*p ..]`?

I have defined:

```
Prelude> let factors p t = [t+0*p, t+1*p ..]
```

I want to efficiently represent an infinite list that is the difference of `[0..]` and `factors p t`, but using `\\` from [`Data.List`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html) requires too much memory for even medium-sized lists:

```
Prelude Data.List> [0..10000] \\ (factors 5 0)
<interactive>: out of memory
```

I know that I can represent the values between `t+0*p` and `t+1*p` with:

```
Prelude> let innerList p1 p2 t = [t+p1+1, t+p1+2 .. t+p2-1]
Prelude> innerList 0 5 0
[1,2,3,4]
```

However, repeatedly calculating and concatenating `innerList` for increasing intervals seems clumsy.

Can I efficiently represent `[0..] \\ (factors p t)` without calculating `rem` or `mod` for each element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the infinite list `[0..] \\ [t,t+p..]`,

```
yourlist t p = [0..t-1] ++ [i | m <- [0,p..], i <- [t+m+1..t+m+p-1]]
```

---

Of course this approach doesn't scale, at all, if you'd want to remove some other factors, like

```
[0..] \\ [t,t+p..] \\ [s,s+q..] \\ ...
```

in which case you'll have to remove them in sequence with `minus`, mentioned in Daniel Fischer's answer. There is no magic bullet here.

But [there's also a `union`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_features#Hamming_numbers), with which the above becomes

```
[0..] \\ ( [t,t+p..] `union` [s,s+q..] `union` ... )
```

the advantage is, we can [arrange the unions in a tree](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold#Tree-like_folds), and get algorithmic improvement.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `(\\)` for that, because

```
(\\)                    :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(\\)                    =  foldl (flip delete)
```

the list of elements you want to remove is infinite, and a left fold never terminates when the list it folds over is infinite.

If you rather want to use something already written than write it yourself, you can use [minus](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-ordlist/0.4.5/doc/html/Data-List-Ordered.html#v%3aminus) from the [data-ordlist](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.5) package.

The performance should be adequate.

Otherwise,

```
minus :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
minus xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys)
    | x < y     = x : minus xs yys
    | x == y    = minus xs ys
    | otherwise = minus xss ys
minus xs _      = xs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehesion with a predicate, using [rem](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3arem):

```
>>> let t = 0
>>> let p = 5
>>> take 40 $ [ x | x <- [1..], x `rem` p /= t ]
[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,26,27,28,29,31,32,33,34,36,37,38,39,41,42,43,44,46,47,48,49]
```

Comment: I intend to use this with extremely large lists, so unfortunately, calculating `rem` or `mod` for each element is undesirable.

Comment: @robjb How large are your lists going to be?

Comment: One of the lists from my test data that needs to be separated into factors and non-factors is `[0..2326203125] :: Integer`, and the computation will be repeated for multiple `p`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want efficiency, why does your solution have to use list comprehension syntax?

Why not something like this?

```
 gen' n i p | i == p = gen' (n + p) 1 p
 gen' n i p = (n+i) : gen' n (i+1) p
 gen = gen' 0 1
```

and then do

```
 gen 5
```

Comment: I think the idea is right, but you miss `0` and ignore the offset/remainder (`t`).

Answer (score 1):

Because you have ascending lists, you can simply lazily merge them:

```
 nums = [1..]
 nogos = factors p t
 result = merge nums (dropWhile (<head nums) nogos) where
      merge (a:as) (b:bs)
        | a < b = a : merge as (b:bs)
        | a == b = merge as bs
        | otherwise = error "should not happen"
```

Writing this in a general way so that we have a function that builds the difference of two infinite lists, provided only that they are in ascending order, is left as exercise. In the end, the following should be possible

```
 [1..] `infiniteDifference` primes `infiniteDifference` squares
```

For this, make it a left associative operator.